# SQL != ALL() Difficulty

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For the query I am trying to write for an Oracle SQL database, I am simply trying to get all of the rows from the CI table that are owned by someone/something not listed in the sys_user table yet the results returned by the query below upon manual inspection are in fact found in the sys_user table.  Stranger stil, all returned values for owner_id are the same.

```
SELECT
  ci.sys_id as product_id,
  ci.name as product,
  ci.sys_class_name as class_name,
  ci.owned_by as owner_id
FROM 
    EDQ_EDW.CMDB_CI CI,
  EDQ_EDW.CMDB_SYS_USER usr
WHERE
    ci.owned_by is not null
  and ci.owned_by != all(usr.sys_id)
```

I've double checked with the Oracle documentation to make sure that I'm not using != ALL() incorrectly, and I don't believe I am.  What is causing this?

Comment: what's the result of `select * from EDQ_EDW.CMDB_SYS_USER where sys_id is null;`

Comment: Also, I'm never really using this `all` comparator but it seems according to the doc that it should be followed by a list or a subquery...

Comment: Can you post the query you used to create and insert EDQ_EDW.CMDB_CI rows?

Comment: sys_id is the key, so it can't be null.  Owned_by, however, can be null.
@cdummy: EDQ_EDW.cmdb_ci was not populated by me, though that's irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALL`, `SOME` and `ANY` conditions work from a rowset, not from a scalar value like you have in your query. Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  ci.sys_id as product_id,
  ci.name as product,
  ci.sys_class_name as class_name,
  ci.owned_by as owner_id
FROM EDQ_EDW.CMDB_CI CI
WHERE ci.owned_by is not null
  AND ci.owned_by != ALL (SELECT sys_id FROM EDQ_EDW.CMDB_SYS_USER)
```

I'm not sure if the logic is right on this, though the syntax should be OK. If you don't get the results you want, try `NOT IN` instead:

```
SELECT
  ci.sys_id as product_id,
  ci.name as product,
  ci.sys_class_name as class_name,
  ci.owned_by as owner_id
FROM EDQ_EDW.CMDB_CI CI
WHERE ci.owned_by is not null
  AND ci.owned_by NOT IN (SELECT sys_id FROM EDQ_EDW.CMDB_SYS_USER)
```

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` or a "left-join and check for NULL" query. These are faster in certain situations. You can find an explanation using nice, simple examples [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/).